# How to do Rest PUT/POST in groovy

Tags: rest, groovy

How to do HTTP PUT/POSTs from inside Groovy code without having to import any libraries (if at all possible)? I know there is a simple getText() methods that Groovy adds to the java.net.URL class, that could be used without adding any dependencies. Is there a way to do Rest PUT in the same fashion?

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with `HttpURLConnection` in a similar way as you would do it with java:

```
def url = new URL('http://your_rest_endpoint')
def http = url.openConnection()
http.setDoOutput(true)
http.setRequestMethod('PUT')
http.setRequestProperty('User-agent', 'groovy script')

def out = new OutputStreamWriter(http.outputStream)
out.write('data')
out.close()

http.inputStream // read server response from it
```

Comment: To put a fine point here, the example `'data'` is the POST or PUT body, often JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

```
import groovyx.net.http.RESTClient
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

url = "http://restapi3.apiary.io"

@Grab (group = 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module = 'http-builder', version = '0.5.0')
def client = new RESTClient(url)

def jsonObj = new JsonSlurper().parseText('{ "title": "Pick-up posters from Post-Office" }')
def response = client.put(path: "/notes/id",
  contentType: JSON,
  body: jsonObj,
  headers: [Accept: 'application/json'])

println("Status: " + response.status)
if (response.data) {
  println("Content Type: " + response.contentType)
  println("Headers: " + response.getAllHeaders())
  println("Body:\n" + JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(response.data)))
}
```